# Annoying Square Appears as Background Image in Weather App

Tags: javascript, html, css, debugging, background

Hi i recently started a project in js which is called a Weather App . Im making this project to like learn fetch api and later on ill add css trsnsitions and animations anyways ive did the whole project functional and everything but the prob is look [Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKbgj.png) As you can see my fellow programmers there is this annoying square in the like home screen thingy i want to know how to remove it

Js Code :

```
const apiKey = "6997e66c1b3106660cb9cef841fd76f6";
const cityInp = document.getElementById("Cityinput");
const weatherImage = document.getElementById("weatherImage");

function Search() {
  const city = cityInp.value;
  fetch(
    `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${apiKey}`
  )
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then((data) => {
      const Weatherinfo = document.getElementById("weatherDetails");
      let weatherCondition = "";

      if (data.weather && data.weather.length > 0) {
        weatherCondition = data.weather[0].main;
      }
      const celsiusTemperature = parseInt(data.main.temp) - 273.15;
      const details = `<h2>${data.name}</h2>
            <p>${weatherCondition}</p>
            <p>Temperature: ${celsiusTemperature.toFixed(2)}°C</p>`;
      Weatherinfo.innerHTML = details;

      switch (weatherCondition) {
        case "Clear":
          weatherImage.src = "images/clear.png";
          break;
        case "Clouds":
          weatherImage.src = "images/cloud.png";
          break;
        case "Rain":
          weatherImage.src = "images/rain.png";
          break;
        case "Snow":
          weatherImage.src = "images/snow.png";
          break;
        case "Haze":
          weatherImage.src = "images/mist.png";
          break;
        default:
          weatherImage.src = "images/def.png";
      }
    });
}
```

Html Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Weather App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Entry">
        <input type="text" id="Cityinput" placeholder="Enter a location">
        <button onclick="Search()"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">
            search
            </span></button>
        </div>
    <div id="weatherDetails">
    </div>
    <img src="" alt="" id="weatherImage">

    
</body>
<script src="Fetch.js"></script>
</html>
```

Ive been trying to remove the square , i tried, changing background of the switch case default image at the end to a similar image of the background nothing happened and please if you answer try to also explain while answering im a quiite begiiner

Comment: By "annoying square" do you mean (what appears to be) that broken `<img>` element?  When you examine the DOM for that page in your browser's debugging tools, what is the `src` for that `<img>`?  Is it what you expect?

Comment: I'm afraid that "yea bro help me" doesn't really add much information about the problem.  If you're not familiar with your browser's debugging tools then now is a great time to start using those.  With the DOM explorer you can examine the state of the elements on the page.  With the Network tab you can examine the requests/responses for things like images.  With the Script Debugger you can step through the code line by line as it executes and observe its exact behavior and values of variables.  When you do this, which specific operation isn't doing what you expect?

Comment: Alternatively, if you can provide a [mcve] of the problem in the question, this community can observe the problem and know more about it to help.

Comment: What i mean bro is that um it doesnt show anything when i go and use debug tools i just wanna get rid of the square with the broken image As you can see from the image i provided

Comment: *"i just wanna get rid of the square"* - Presumably there is some HTML element (likely an `<img>` element) producing this output.  If your goal is to remove it, have you tried removing it from your HTML?  Try to understand that nobody here can see the HTML code that you're not showing us, so it's difficult to be more specific.  But presumably the code `document.getElementById("weatherImage")` is referencing an `<img>` (or similar) element, with an `id` value of `"weatherImage"`.  If you want to remove that element, your first step would be to edit the HTML and remove it.

Comment: I Uploaded the html just for clarrification 'document.getElementById("weatherImage")' is for the weathr image like sunny cloudy rainy and thoose weathers

Comment: Can you not just remove the img tag? `<img src="" alt="" id="weatherImage">`?

Comment: @laithmaree: And have you looked at that HTML?  At a glance I see this element: `<img src="" alt="" id="weatherImage">`  Is that the element you want to get rid of?  Have you tried getting rid of it?  Or are you trying to do something else besides getting rid of it that you haven't been able to clarify?  We can appreciate that you're new to this, but so far you haven't been particularly clear about what you're trying to do or what specific problem is preventing you from doing it.

Comment: I did try to do that infact as you mention it now i tried but you see umm now it removed entire images so there's no images like 'Sun' 'Cloud' and thoose

Comment: @laithmaree: This is where you're being unclear.  That "annoying box" is the `<img>` element, but with a non-functioning `src` value.  You *said* that you want to remove it.  Which you would accomplish by removing it.  But if you *don't* want to remove it, then now is the time to be more specific about the problem.  Is the problem that it should be displaying an image?  Is the problem that it should conditionally display depending on whether or not a `src` is set at all?  Is the problem that you want it to display some default image at first?  Is the problem something else?  Please clarify.

Comment: first im sorry if your getting mad at me and to answer your question is i dont want that white borderd box in the main page before it displays the image and the details its just there no matter what You see the images i posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That "annoying square" is the `<img>` element:

```
<img src="" alt="" id="weatherImage">
```

It's not displaying an image because, well, what image do you expect it to display?  The `src` attribute specifies the source of the image.  And `""` doesn't specify anything.  So it's successfully displaying the (lack of) image specified.  (The icon within the square is the browser's default indication that the page is trying and failing to show an image.)

One approach would be to display a *default* image of some kind.  Something like:

```
<img src="" alt="images/def.png" id="weatherImage">
```

(Or whatever default image value you'd want to display.)

Another option is to style the element to be hidden.  For example, you can add a CSS class to hide something:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

And include that class in the element by default:

```
<img src="" alt="" id="weatherImage" class="hidden">
```

Then in your JavaScript code, remove that class when displaying an image:

```
weatherImage.classList.remove("hidden");
```

If at any point you want to re-hide the element, just add the class again:

```
weatherImage.classList.add("hidden");
```